# Why is Nil coalescing operator Right Associative?

Tags: swift, operators, null-coalescing-operator, associativity, custom-operator

Shouldn’t it be Left Associative?

I think

```
let a = b ?? c ?? d
```

is grouped like

```
let a = (b ?? c) ?? d
```

not

```
let a = b ?? (c ?? d)
```

But it is declared as a Right Associative. Do I misunderstand or miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's an optimization. Left or right association doesn't change the result.

This:

```
(b ?? c) ?? d
```

evaluates `b ?? c`, and its result is used as the left side of `x ?? d`. So even if `b` is not null, the coalescing operator is executed 2 times.

In this case instead

```
b ?? (c ?? d)
```

if `b` is not nil, the expression at the right side is not evaluated, hence not executed

---

**Addendum**

To prove that, I made a simple test: I (re)defined the nil coalescing operator:

```
infix operator !!! {
    associativity left
    precedence 110
}

func !!!<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> T?) -> T? {
    if let value = optional {
        println(optional)
        return value
    }

    let def = defaultValue()
    println(def)
    return def
}
```

With this test data:

```
let a: String? = "a"
let b: String? = "b"
let c: String? = "c"

let d = a !!! b !!! c
```

Using `associativity left`, this is what's printed to the console:

```
Optional("a")
Optional("a")
```

whereas changing the associativity to `right`, the output is:

```
Optional("a")
```

That means when using right associativity the right side of the operator is ignored if the left is not nil.

Comment: I think in
````
b ?? (c ?? d)
````
the (c ?? d?) should be evaluated before checking if b is nil because they are in parenthesis. So those expression would be evaluated even though b is not nil but they are not.

Comment: But I can see your point on the evaluation of these expression which is a great point.
So does this imply that the Nil Coalescing has a special evaluation rule?

Comment: I don't think it's a special evaluation rule. It works with both left and right associativity, but in the latter case its execution is more optimized. See updated answer

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I forgot to considering the @autoclosure. Your example is so great for explain this.

Comment: I used your code snippet and remove @autoclosure, the result is like what I expect.

Comment: +1 Just for completeness I'll mention that we could have `f() ?? g() ?? h()` where `f` may throw if `g` is called first, etc.  In this case, order does matter.